# jQuery File Upload Plugin - upload multiple files to different url's (Vimeo)

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm using the great jQuery File Upload Plugin to upload files to Vimeo.

upload one file at a time works great, my problem is when I try to upload multiple files into Vimeo .

Vimeo give me a ticket_id and upload_link_secure (url) for each file, how to a change the url of the plugin for each file in run time??
I'm using the File Upload widget.

Thank you

Comment: I took the code from https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ and tried to play with the different events in order to change the url. no success. No I'm trying to implement my own drop zone and dynamicaly add fileupload for each file

Comment: no good. got no where